# Is a brand singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

Collective nouns are so confusing.
I saw a grammar tip that says using singular form for a company, but I have a tendency to make it plural.

1: The technology of Nike is extremely amazing. And it is its only true competitor, too. It strives to improve its products and never stop trying new things.

2: The technology of Nike is extremely amazing. And They are their only true competitor, too. They strive to improve their products and never stop trying new things.

Which one sounds better?

Comment: In Am or Br English?

Comment: I could live with either, but not *It strives to improve its products and never stop*. I'd put *stops* there.

Comment: It's not a brand issue. It's whether you see a company as it (singular) or its people (plural).

Comment: @Yosef _It's whether you see a company as it (singular) or its people (plural) in the sentence being considered._ [Assuming you adopt synesis.]